# How to set limit for getting items from rss feed?

Tags: ajax, angular, meteor, rss, medium.com-publishing-api

I'm getting feed from [this link](https://buzz.machaao.com/feed). I want to get only first five items from feed. Instead of that I'm getting all of the items from feed. How can I get first five items only ?. Should I pass any parameters with URL ?

```
HTTP.get('https://buzz.machaao.com/feed',
  (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible. What you can do though is to make a GET request to `https://buzz.machaao.com/latest` with `Accept: application/json` header. You can pass a `count` parameter to limit the posts.